# display images and videos in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was trying to list all the images and videos in a folder but setting it in recyclerview nor gridview gives a good result. it stucks in the scroll. Please suggest a way how to display all the files in a better way.

This is how i fetch files,

```
listFile = AllUtils.getFiles(fetchPath, mContext);
```

displaying part in recyclerview

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DetailViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (listFile.get(position).toString().contains("mp4")) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(listFile.get(position).toString(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        holder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        holder.ivPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various **free open-source** libraries are available for android on GitHub for working with images and videos.

I think using `BitMap` for displaying images is not a good idea instead of `BitMap` you should use `Glide` library for displaying images and use `fenster` for videos.

**Import Glide in your project**

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}
```

**Display Image like this:**

```
  GlideApp
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

**You can also upload image using url**

```
  GlideApp.with(this).load("http://........").into(imageView);
```

**read more about [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
and [fenster.](https://github.com/malmstein/fenster)**

Comment: glide made it easy fa images. checking fenster for video thumbnails. Thanks.

Comment: @A2N Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was showing images from list in recylerview. Since recylerview caches and recyles the views inside itself getting position in recylerview may fail for your index in listfile. By increasing the cache size of your recylerview to the number of items in listfile makes sures that the position in recylerview is the exact position in your listfile. 
Add this line of code to your recylerview before setting adapter.

```
// Let's say you have 30 items in your listfile
// Or if you cannot make sure the number of items give a bigger number 
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
```

Hope it helps.